# Aiogram 3 AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x, sendmessage

Помогите исправить ошибку. Dispatcher не содержит message_handler. Как теперь это можно реализовать?

```
bot = aiogram.Bot(token, protect_content=1)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dispatcher = aiogram.Dispatcher(storage=storage)

@dispatcher.message_handler(state=state)
async def getname(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await message.answer("Well done")
    await MyStates.name2.set()

async def main() -> None:
    bot = Bot(token, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    await dispatcher.start_polling(bot)
```

Comment: Можете отправить полный код вашего модуля? Вероятнее всего, вы неправильно используйте переменную dispatcher

Comment: При запуске бота должны все выглядеть примерно так: await dispatcher.start_polling(bot)

Comment: У меня конкретно с декоратором проблемы(

Comment: Похоже что @dispatcher.message_handler был заменен чем-то другим. Я ничего не нашёл

Comment: Всё спасибо я уже нашёл решение

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html#finite-state-machine - Finite State Machine Example - Aiogram 3 Используйте фулл код. Оттуда декораторы берите